# How do you delete a ClearCase branch type?

Tags: branch, clearcase

With ClearCase, you create views with `cleartool mkview`, and delete them with `cleartool rmview`. Similarly, you create branch types with:

```
cleartool mkbrtype -c "some comment" my_brance_type
```

... but there is no `cleartool rmbrtype` which would be the opposite command. How *do* you remove a branch type in CMake?

Answer (score 0):

The unintuitive command for removing a branch type is:

```
ct rmtype -rmall brtype:my_branch_type
```

See the [detailed documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmtype.htm) about this on IBM's website.

Note: The `-rmall` is often (always?) necessary even if you don't have any objects with revisions of that branch type. (At least with ClearCase v8.0.0.x.)

Answer (score 0):

Warning: a [`cleartool rmtype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmtype.htm) won't succeed if you have any instance of the type you want to remove.

Even with `-rmall`, it can still fail if the instance you remove (here a branch based on a brtype) has hyperlink and other UCM metadata which would be dangling if the branch disappear.

Comment: Actually, metadata pointing to a brtype, or instances of the brtype, will be removed when the type is removed. *UCM* metadata (stream guard links) may prevent the removal of the brtype...

Comment: @BrianCowan Yes, that is why I mentioned only UCM metadata indeed. I remember having a lot of issue with those.